# Writing data to files after few iteration in python

Tags: python

I want to write data into five files on every fifth iteration, is there any way to do that, I am confused how to fetch the past data

```
   i=1
   while 1:
   data = random.randint(0,100) 
   print(data)
   if(i%5==0):
       with open('D:\mydata\my%d.csv'%(i-4),'D:\mydata\my%d.csv'%(i-3), "w") as csv_file:   
           writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
           level_counter = 0
           max_levels = 1
           while level_counter < max_levels:
               filename1 = data
               writer.writerow(("No load", filename1)) 
               level_counter = level_counter +1 
               print("done")
   i=i+1
   time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: If your intention is to append the data to the file every 5th iteration, then open the file in append mode, rather than write mode.  Otherwise, you'll just overwrite you old data every time.

Comment: No, I want to write 5 different file

Answer (score 1):

Just use a list to store data from the past 5 iterations:

```
i = 1
past_data = []
while True:
    data = random.randint(0, 100)
    past_data.append(data)
    if i % 5 == 0:
        ...
        past_data = []
i += 1
```

Comment: I need five different files and not in a single file.

Comment: In this case, using the code from above, you could iterate through the 5 entries of `past_data` and append each entry to a different file. An alternative is to create a list of five files `cache = [[fileA], ..., [fileE]]` and write to`cache[i%5]` after iteration i.